# How to invoke a thunk for sub-object property access in JS?

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype-programming

There is a class of objects to which I need to lazy add a few functions as properties after the fact. Because these functions must reference instance variables in order to configure the function attached as a property, I've used thunks to create the function and forward the first function call. for a simplified example:

```js
function Foo(val) {
  this.val = val;
}

// simulates a library call which returns a complex object with methods
// this library call requires access to some of the object information,
// simulated by passing in `type`
function buildWorkFunction(type) {
  var f = function() { return this.val; };
  if (type === 'string')
    f = function() { return this.val.length; };
  f.getType = function() { return type; };
  return f;
}

function addProperty(Base, prop) {
  var thunk = function() {
    // typeof is just a simple example of how buildWorkFunction could
    // change based on this.val
    this[prop] = buildWorkFunction(typeof this.val);
    return this[prop].apply(this, arguments);
  };
  thunk.getType = function() {
    return 'TODO'; // <-- this is the part I need help with
  };
  Base.prototype[prop] = thunk;
}

// simulates instances existing before the module load
var foo = new Foo('foo');

// runs after user requests a module load, runs from the module
setTimeout(function() {
  // adding a module specific property to the non-module model
  addProperty(Foo, 'getVal');

  console.log(foo.getVal());
  console.log(foo.getVal.getType());

  // simulates instances created after the module load
  var bar = new Foo(17);
  console.log(bar.getVal.getType()); // called before thunk - fails
  console.log(bar.getVal());
  console.log(bar.getVal.getType()); // called after thunk - works
}, 0);
```

One problem I have left is that the property's value itself has properties which the application code sometimes references without calling the property itself, as with `f.getType` above. How can I properly catch/proxy/forward calls such as `foo.getVal.getType()` without first calling `foo.getVal()`? The names of the attached properties are well defined and can be shared - but I can't see how to access the correct `this` or the data from them.

Comment: I don't understand your reason why these functions would need to be lazy thunks, but I also don't understand what this has to do with `getType`. That "method of a method" wouldn't work even if the method was not lazy.

Comment: In this instance they do not. In the application, they are added after the user has loaded a module and a network call has completed. The `getType` method simulates methods which provide sorting and other features from a library which generates the property.

Comment: So you're saying the thunk loads the module which then provides the real implementation? Interesting…

Comment: Regarding the "sorting and other features", do you refer to the `this.val` property? Shouldn't the call then rather be `bar.getVal().sort()` or so, instead of `bar.getVal.sort()`? Maybe if you could post (or link) the real code I'd understand your use case better.

Comment: The thunk is added by the module load; the module load doesn't track down all instances of the object to uplift them individually - I reasoned keeping track of them all from everywhere would be logistically infeasible.

Comment: `bar.getVal.getType()` is not a typo. The whole set of related code is several hundred lines and involves a third party framework - I felt it would distract from the question to bring it in, as the framework itself is irrelevant to what I've tried to do. Is there a way to start a conversation not in the comments? I've seen moderators move such.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129947/discussion-between-bergi-and-iiridayn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I properly catch/proxy calls such as `foo.getVal.getType()`? If `foo.getVal()` isn't called first, I can't see how to access the correct this or the data from them.

You can use the same approach as you already did, but on the property getter level instead of the method call level. This makes it possible to lazily create arbitrary instance properties:

```
function addProperty(Base, prop) {
  Object.defineProperty(Base.prototype, prop, {
    get: function thunk() {
      var propertyValue = buildWorkFunction(typeof this.val);
      //                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ access the instance here
      // overwrite (shadow) the prototype getter:
      Object.defineProperty(this, prop, {
        value: propertyValue,
        writable: true,
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
      });
      return this[prop];
    },
    enumerable: true, // dunno
    configurable: true
  });
}
```